# How do I get a .csv file of thousands of GPS coordinates along a stretch of a highway? (GPS Trace?)

Tags: gps, csv, latitude-longitude, trace

I need a large amount of [latitude, longitude] data points along Texas' I-35 from Hillsboro to Salado. Essentially need a GPS Trace with minimum ~1,000 points.

Comment: convert using gps visualizer  http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/convert_input

Comment: Do the points have to come from actual GPS data?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what tools you have, and if the data does not need to be survey quality data, and you are not concerned with elevations, a possible way is as follows:

1. Free-hand trace a line along I-35 between the points of interest in **Google Earth** (free download).
2. Export the line to **kmz** and unzip it as a **kml** file (kmz is a zip file and can be extracted with 7-zip for example)
3. Import kml into **QGIS**
4. Use the **SAGA Convert polygon/line vertices to points** tool to convert line to points.(The file should be in **EPSG:4326 WGS84**).
5. Compute the coordinates of the points in the attribute table of the new point file with the field calculator.
6. Right click new points layer and saveas **csv** format in the next popup.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if this covers your use case, but you can also try to get the data from OpenStreetMap.

Here is list of all the lines representing the I-35 road http://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/2145726#map=8/31.143/-97.414

Having this exported to xml http://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/relation/2145726

You can then download each path as xml http://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/way/130431769

Where you again get reference to each node as xml http://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/node/1436597271

Doing this manually is of course not solution, you would have to script few lines of code around it.

```
    for path in relation:
        for node in path:
            coords = [node.lat, node.lon]
```